# Обращение к ресурсам wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, resources

Добавил gif в ресурсы, указал `действие при сборке - Resource`, в `xaml` пишу

```
<MediaElement x:Name="myGif" MediaEnded="myGif_MediaEnded" UnloadedBehavior="Manual"     Source="Resources\127.gif" LoadedBehavior="Play" Stretch="None"/>
```

где

```
private void myGif_MediaEnded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    myGif.Position = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);
    myGif.Play();
}
```

Но гифка не производится, если указать в `xaml` путь к гифке, что лежит на жд `Source="D:\..\127.gif"`, то воспроизведение пройдет удачно.

В чем может быть проблема ?

p.s Пробовал и так  `Source="pack://application:,,,/Resources/127.gif"`, но гифка не работает, хотя в самом приложении она отображается (до компиляции)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Сделайте действие при сборке Content и копируйте его в выходную папку. Тогда сможете обращаться просто по относительному пути

Comment: @AntonShakalo мне придется все время "таскать с собой" папку и этот файл?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну, собственно, такое поведение документировано, читайте комментарии: [Класс `MediaElement`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.controls.mediaelement(v=vs.110).aspx#%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B8)

Наиболее простым видится воспользоваться готовым средством для отображения Gif-анимации в штатном `Image`, для этого подключите в проект пакет [WpfAnimatedGif](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WpfAnimatedGif) и воспользуйтесь им:

```
<Image xmlns:gif="http://wpfanimatedgif.codeplex.com"
       gif:ImageBehavior.AnimatedSource="file.gif"/>
```

Comment: спасибо, а есть ли способы сделать тоже самое, но без сторонних либ ? хочется на выходе иметь один ехе

Comment: Можете скопировать код к себе в проект (в лицезировании я не разбираюсь), его там не сильно много: https://github.com/XamlAnimatedGif/WpfAnimatedGif/tree/master/WpfAnimatedGif

Comment: спасибо, попробую

Comment: скопировал, везде изменил namespace на свой, но все равно дает ошибки :
`не удалось найти присоединяемое свойство "AnimatedSource`, `ImageBehavior" не существует в пространстве имен "http://wpfanimatedgif.codeplex.com` ,
`свойство "ImageBehavior.AnimatedSource" не существует в пространстве имен XML "http://wpfanimatedgif.codeplex.com`

Comment: не подскажите, что сделал не так ?

Comment: в `xmlns:gif` укажите не `http://wpfanimatedgif.codeplex.com`, а свое пространство имен

Comment: тоже так делал, но ошибка та же
`ImageBehavior" не существует в пространстве имен "Widget"`

Comment: хотя в самом cs файле ImageBehavior,cs я поставил свой namespace

Comment: Уберите `gif:ImageBehavior.AnimatedSource="file.gif"`, скомпилируйте проект без него, если скомпилировалось нормально — добавляйте еще раз, всё должно сработать

Comment: исправил, оказалось, надо в `xmlns:gif=` добавить `clr-namespace:` , т.е получится так :
`xmlns:gif="clr-namespace:Widget" `

Comment: Ну это да, там сама студия даже подсказывать должна при вводе.

Comment: ага. Кстати, а эта либа разве не работает с ресурсами ? если указать ей файл, как ресурс, ты выдает ошибку при запуске, а если сделать гифку, как содержание (content ), то все норм. Я почему-то думал, что она может работать с ресурсом

Comment: Не знаю, не использовал ее никогда :) Просто нагуглил на enSO. Можете на гитхабе разработчику вопрос написать

Comment: разобрался , спасибо большое за помощь